# Is c# compatible with autocad lt?

Tags: c#, autocad

I've looked for this question several times but there's no answer. Lisp is a language that is exclusive to the full version of autocad, I wonder if c# is as well or if I can run c# on a lt version of autocad.

Comment: Again, i didnt ask for autocad, but "autocad lt", please learn to read before downvoting.

Comment: @anotherJ.Doe - this question is off topic for stack overflow since it's regarding the feature set of some piece of software and that software is not programming related. If this were a question about make, or gcc, it'd be fine, but AutoCad doesn't fall under that bucket. The answer to this question won't enrich the software development community, which is the ultimate goal of StackOverflow. This is why you're getting downvotes. You might have better luck asking on SuperUser instead.

Comment: Actually a lot of programming is done in Autocad. It's true this question would be better in superuser, but claiming it's a poor question because it envolves autocad is just a poor excuse to justify the bash wish.

Comment: @anotherJ.Doe - whether or not programming is done in AutoCad is irrelevant. Your question does not meet the help center's definition for a question that is appropriate here, and frequently that translates into downvotes. Right now there are two close votes against your question (one of which is mine), because this is the wrong place to ask your question. You're not getting downvoted here because people have anything against you or AutoCad. You're getting downvotes because you asked the wrong community to help you. Want to know how to do something in C#? Please, ask away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoCAD LT versions do not support any programmation. 
This is, with the 3d modeling, the main difference between LT versions and 'full' versions.